# Symfony 2 Controller as a Service: container not injected

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, dependency-injection, controller

I want to be able to inject services into my controllers, so I had a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html and after some fiddling with the notation (could be a little more consistent but whatever) I have my WebTestCase using the service definition entry.

But the controller needs the container itself injected (and does indeed extend ContainerAware via the default framework controller), and the ControllerResolver in the FrameworkBundle does not do that.

Looking at the code (Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver::createController()) this is not suprising:

```
protected function createController($controller)
{
    if (false === strpos($controller, '::')) {
        $count = substr_count($controller, ':');
        if (2 == $count) {
            // controller in the a:b:c notation then
            $controller = $this->parser->parse($controller);
        } elseif (1 == $count) {
            // controller in the service:method notation
            list($service, $method) = explode(':', $controller, 2);

            return array($this->container->get($service), $method);
        } else {
            throw new \LogicException(sprintf('Unable to parse the controller name "%s".', $controller));
        }
    }

    list($class, $method) = explode('::', $controller, 2);

    if (!class_exists($class)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Class "%s" does not exist.', $class));
    }

    $controller = new $class();
    if ($controller instanceof ContainerAwareInterface) {
        $controller->setContainer($this->container);
    }

    return array($controller, $method);
}
```

Apparently when using service:method notation,, it directly returns the controller from the container, not injecting the container itself.

Is this is a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Apparently this is "wanted" or at least expected behavior: I should inject everything or nothing. I can live with that.

Comment: This also works: calls: 
          - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]

Comment: Can't answer my own question but consider this one solved.

Comment: Yep.  It is by intent.  It's gives you the option of not having the container injected at all.  Which is a laudable goal.

Comment: As soon as the base controller is ContainerAware, the service container should inject it all time (if a controller extends it). I agree with you, that's a strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. It works as expected. This workflow generally "protects" the `Controller as a Service` concept. This way You need to look at `Controller` as a regular `Service`. In regular `Service` You inject everything what You need - if You need the controller itself - inject it explicitly.

To explain it more clearly, this "protection" I mentioned helps to avoid using `service:method` notation in one place and `controller::method` or `bundle:controller:method` in another.

So if not this "protection" it would be difficult to state that particular `Controller` is described as a Service or not as this would depend on which notation will be called first in `Container` build-up.